# parse values from a JSON data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Using JQuery, I am trying to parse values from a JSON data.
i have the following JSON data:

```
{
  "VMServer": "VM Server 1",
  "VMs": [{
    "ID": "AND-4.1",
    "OS": "Android- 4.1",
    "FLAVOUR": "",
    "CAPS": {
      "IE": "10",
      "FF": "28",
      "GC": "32"
    },
    "DEVICE": {
      "SAMSSU": [
        "S3",
        "S4"
      ],
      "LG": [
        "G3",
        "G4"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

using below code to extract data from josn.

```
function loadPlatforms(callback) {
  $.getJSON('/getAllVMs', function (data) {

    var html = '';
    var capVMs = {};
    var VMSs = Object.keys(data);
    VMSs.forEach(function(VMS) {
      if(data[VMS].length > 0) {
        data[VMS].forEach(function (val) {
          for(var brc in gBrowsers) {
            if(val.CAPS.hasOwnProperty(brc)) {
              var cap = val.OS + '-' + brc + '-' + val.CAPS[brc];
              alert(val.DEVICE)
              var ds = Object.keys(val.DEVICE);
              ds.forEach(function (bb) {

            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
      });
}
```

But I am getting type error!!

```
TypeError:val.DEVICE is not an object
var ds =   Object.keys(val.DEVICE);
```

while alerting val.DEVICE it outputs 3 times two alert showing valid data and third alert showing `undefined`
i don't know how it is happening. what's wrong with my code.

Comment: alert(data); what is giving this to you?

Answer (score 0):

when you are getting json data store it in some variable say:

var myJsondata = {your json data};

try in the similar way:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(myJsondata);
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

for getting values in your json you can use

```
alert(obj.VMServer);
```

for further data you can use

```
alert(obj.vms[0].ID =="AND-4.1" );
alert(obj.vms[0].Device.samssu[0].s3);
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're trying to access DEVICE on the wrong object.

Try breaking your code out more ( separating concerns ).  Add some console.log statements in there and you should be able to quickly see where it is happening.

Above all, I would start refactoring immediately.  Code Readability here is perhaps your biggest problem, which is making it hard for you to debug.  If you can split this up into manageable chunks and give your variable names more descriptive meaning ( rather than trying to keep them simple/small ) then it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
VMSs.forEach(function(VMS) {
    if(data[VMS].length > 0) { 
            console.log(data[VMS].length); 
    }
});
//input: 11 , 1
```

`VMSs.forEach` may be loop twice .the error may be cause by the data loop  ,check you data and use `console.log` print data;